# loadComplete event gets fired on each filter operation in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, event-handling

According to jqGrid [wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) page, "This event is executed immediately after every server request."

In my grid, I've a filter toolbar on top.

```
$(table_data_obj).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:true, autosearch:true, defaultSearch:'cn'});
```

and loadComplete function like:

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
 data_processing(data);
}
```

Whenever, I filter grid data locally (no new server request), data_processing(data) is being called. And I do not want this behavior. How can I make sure that data_processing(data) gets called only with new server requests.

**Edit**
I want to do some data processing, everytime new data is fetched from server. Is there a better place for that ?

Comment: my hacked solution: checking for data.rows[0].cell inside data_processing(data). Cell object is present only in server response data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't posted the jqGrid definition and not describes why you have sometime data from the server and sometime locally. I suppose that you use `loadonce:true` option and sometime reset `datatype` parameter of jqGrid to the original value 'json' or 'xml' if you need to reload data from the server. If it is your case I would recommend you to test whether the `datatype` parameter are 'local' or not. You can use either the if like `if ($("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','datatype') !== 'json') {/* local data */}` or use just `$("#list")[0].p.datatype` instead of `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','datatype')`.  If the data are loaded from the server the `datatype` will be 'json' (or 'xml'). **After** processing of `loadComplete` event the `datatype` will be changed to the 'local' if you use `loadonce:true` option.

Answer (score 0):

use firebug to watch the request to server. check params, u'll get idea which values are being posted. use alerts in events to figure out the specific event throwing server request

Comment: no new server requests, as already mentioned in question. its just the event which is being fired on filtering data.

Comment: ur function data_processing() will be called on loadcomplete () ultimately on each filter. gridcomplete() can be used koz u hav all the data.first u say no server request, then u say yes server request(check ur edit)

Comment: I want data_processing() to be called on each new server request, not while filtering data. And gridcomplete is also called in filtering.

Comment: receive the data thru $.ajax function, keep that data in some array in json format and process that data on loadcomplete() function, ur array will be accessible in loadcomplete event. plus when data is retrieved, u can use clientAray. read trirand how to use clientArray.